# Writing a Function That Categorizes a Numerical Vector Using mutate() and ifelse()

Tags: r, function, categorical-data, dplyr

Forgive me if this a beginner's question. I'm relatively new to R. I'm practicing writing functions. I'm currently trying to write a function that takes any numerical vector that represents time and categorizes each observation into the following categories: "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening", and "Night". All of the vectors representing time are in military time.

```
time_cat <- function(df, column) {
 select(df, column) %>%
 mutate(time_category = ifelse(column %in% 500:1159, "Morning", 
                           ifelse(column %in% 1200:1659, "Afternoon", 
                                  ifelse(column %in% 1700:2059, "Evening", "Night"))))
}
```

I'm using the flights dataset from the nycflights13 package for practice. However, the function seems to be incorrectly categorizing all observations into the "Night" category.

```
time_cat(flights, "dep_time")
 # A tibble: 336,776 x 2
   dep_time time_category
      <int>         <chr>
 1      517         Night
 2      533         Night
 3      542         Night
 4      544         Night
 5      554         Night
 6      554         Night
 7      555         Night
 8      557         Night
 9      557         Night
10      558         Night
# ... with 336,766 more rows
```

Obviously, all of those observations should be classified as "Morning".

Could someone please explain what is wrong with that code?

I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the call to `time_cat` it is trying to the match the string, `"dep_time"`, to a range of numbers rather than matching the column of that name in the data frame to a range of numbers.

For example, in the code below the `mutate` is comparing `"a" == "b"` in the first call to `f` and `"b" == "b"` in the second.  In neither case is it using the columns `a` or `b`.

```
dd <- data.frame(a = c("a", "b", "c"), b = c("A", "B", "C"))
f <- function(x) dd %>% mutate(new_column = x == "b")
f("a")
##   a b new_column
## 1 a A      FALSE
## 2 b B      FALSE
## 3 c C      FALSE
f("b")
##   a b new_column
## 1 a A       TRUE
## 2 b B       TRUE
## 3 c C       TRUE
```

To get around this, use the tidyeval facilities of the rlang package:

```
time_cat <- function(df, column) {
 column <- sym(column)
 select(df, !!column) %>%
 mutate(time_category = ifelse((!!column) %in% 500:1159, "Morning", 
                           ifelse((!!column) %in% 1200:1659, "Afternoon", 
                                  ifelse((!!column) %in% 1700:2059, "Evening", "Night"))))
}

time_cat(flights, "dep_time")
```

Also you might find it more convenient to use `case_when`.  Also it is usual to start off with the input on the left hand side of the pipe.

```
time_cat <- function(df, column) {
 column <- sym(column)
 df %>%
    select(!!column) %>%
    mutate(time_category = case_when((!!column) %in% 500:1159 ~ "Morning", 
                                     (!!column) %in% 1200:1659 ~ "Afternoon", 
                                     (!!column) %in% 1700:2059 ~ "Evening", 
                                     TRUE ~ "Night"))
}

time_cat(flights, "dep_time")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Rather seems like a job for `cut`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of you will disagree with me but I wouldn't use a function and would solve it with the data.table library like this:

```
library(data.table)
flights <- as.data.table(flights)

flights[dep_time < 1200, time_cat := "Morning"]
flights[dep_time > 1159 & dep_time < 1700, time_cat := "Afternoon"]
flights[dep_time > 1659 & dep_time < 2100, time_cat := "Evening"]
flights[dep_time > 2059, time_cat := "Night"]
```